# Building hundreds of C++ components using multiple threads

Tags: performance, beginner, multithreading, perl

I'm pretty new to Perl (*and multithreading*), so I was wondering if someone would be willing to take a look at my script and give me any tips on increasing performance.

### Motivation

The script is designed to build several hundred C++ components, using multiple threads (one per component)

### Design

At a high level, the script should follow this flow:

- Get parameters
- Default the number of compilation and linking threads to use
- Read in a list of components

  - The format here would be something like, if you pass in 'SERVER', we have a file that maps that component name to ~40 directories that need built
- Launch 16 threads in 'listening' state
- Que up the work to be performed

  - Dependent on the actions passed in

### Code

Commented throughout to clarify what *I expect to be happening*

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use POSIX qw(ceil floor strftime);
use Perl::OSType ':all';

use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;
use List::Util qw(min max);
use Log::Message::Simple qw(msg error debug);
use File;

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Semaphore;

use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @procs;
my @comps;
my @compsCopy;
my @retCodes;
share(@retCodes);

my @failedComponents;
share(@failedComponents);

my $maxThreadsSem = Thread::Semaphore->new(0);

my $compStr = "";

my $MAKE_INVOCATION_PATH;
my $MAKE;

## Parse options and print usage if there is a syntax error,
## or if usage was explicitly requested.
GetOptions('help|?' => \my $help, man => \my $man, 'verbose' => \my $verbose, 'comps:s{,}' => \my @compList, 'COMPLIST:s' => \my $legacyCOMPLIST, 'action:s{1,3}' => \my @actionList,
           'clthreads:i' => \my $clthreads, 'linkthreads:i' => \my $linkthreads) or pod2usage(2);
pod2usage(1) if $help;
pod2usage(-verbose => 2) if $man;

#set silent flag for make
$ENV{SL} = '@' unless $verbose;

@compList = qw(SERVER TOOLS) if !@compList;
@actionList = qw(clean depend build link) if !@actionList;

#default thread counts
### --> The assumption here is that compile consumes less resources than link,
###     so I default to the number of cores for compile, and slightly lower for linking
my $numCores;
if(is_os_type('Windows'))
{
  $numCores = `grep -c '^processor' \/proc\/cpuinfo`;
}
elsif(is_os_type('Unix'))
{
  my $numCoresText = `lsconf | grep Processors`;
  $numCoresText =~ m/(\d+)/;
  $numCores = $1;
}

$clthreads = $numCores if !$clthreads;
$linkthreads = ceil($numCores * .75) if !$linkthreads;

SetMake();
my $startTime = (strftime "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", gmtime);

#the work
BuildInit(@ARGV);

print "Started At: \t$startTime\n";
print "Ended At: \t" . (strftime "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", gmtime) ."\n";

my $maxReturnCode = max @retCodes;
print "Highest Error Code: $maxReturnCode\n";
print "Components with failures: @failedComponents\n" if @failedComponents; 

exit($maxReturnCode);

#----------------------------------------------------------
sub SetMake
{
  if ( $ENV{MAKECMD} ) {
     $MAKE=$ENV{MAKECMD}
  } else {
     # -k option tells make to continue its attempt to build a component after failures.
     # make no longer quits compiling an entire directory after 1 compilation error.
     $MAKE="make -k -C";
  }

  $MAKE_INVOCATION_PATH = $ENV{PATH_CYGDRIVE} || $ENV{PATH};
}

sub BuildInit {

   my $actionStr = "";
   my $compStr = "";                                 

    ### --> Gets the list of directories for each 'component'
    my @component_dirs; 
    foreach my $comp (@compList){
      @component_dirs = (@component_dirs, GetDirs($comp)); 
    }

    ### --> Limit the number of threads that can work at one time
    my $maxThreadsSem = Thread::Semaphore->new($clthreads);    

    print "Action List: @actionList\n";
    print "Component List: @compList\n";
    print "Component Dir List: @component_dirs\n";
    print "Compile Threads: $clthreads\n";
    print "Link Threads: $linkthreads\n";

    #---------------------------------------
    #----   Setup Worker Threads  ---------- 
    for (1..16) {
      async {
         while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
            worker($job);
         }
      };
    }

    #-----------------------------------
    #----   Enqueue The Work  ---------- 
    for my $action (@actionList){
      my $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new(0);  ## used to lock execution between 'actions'

      #manage our resources while linking
      if ($action eq 'link'){
        $maxThreadsSem = Thread::Semaphore->new($linkthreads);
      }
      elsif ($action eq 'build'){
        $maxThreadsSem = Thread::Semaphore->new($clthreads);
      }

      if($action eq 'depend'){
        $ENV{PATH} = "$ENV{BUILD_PATH}/makedepend/bin;" . $ENV{PATH};
        system("rm dependlist") == 0 or die "Failed on attempt to remove dependlist";
        (system("$MAKE $MAKE_INVOCATION_PATH/makedepend")) == 0 or die "Could not build 'makedepend' - killing process";
      }

      ### --> perform 'action' on each 'component directory'
      $q->enqueue([$_, $action, $sem, $maxThreadsSem]) for @component_dirs;

      ### --> we don't want to move on to the next action before this action finishes
      ### --> e.g., we don't want to start linking prior to compiling finishing
      $sem->down(scalar @component_dirs);
      print "\n------>> Waiting for prior actions to finish up... <<------\n";
    }

    # Nothing more to do - notify the Queue that we're not adding anything else
    $q->end();
    for my $thread (threads->list())
    { $thread->join(); }

    return 0;
}

sub worker {
    my ($job) = @_;
    my ($component, $action, $sem, $maxThreadsSem) = @$job;

    #used to throttle the build / link process according the to specified threads
    $maxThreadsSem->down() if $action eq 'link' or $action eq 'build';
    Build($component, $action);
    $sem->up();
    $maxThreadsSem->up() if $action eq 'link' or $action eq 'build';
}

sub Build {

    my ($comp, $action) = @_;
    my $cmd = "$MAKE $MAKE_INVOCATION_PATH/$comp ";
    my $retCode = -1;

    #lack of reliable switch support in perl
    if($action eq "depend")
    {$cmd .= "$action >nul 2>&1"} #suppress output
    elsif($action eq "clean")
    {$cmd .= $action}
    elsif($action eq "build")
    {$cmd .= 'l1'}
    elsif($action eq "link")
    {$cmd .= ''} #add nothing; default is to link
    else {die "Action: $action is unknown to me."}

    print "\n\t\t*** Performing Action: \'$cmd\' on >>> $comp <<< ***" if ($verbose || $action eq 'depend');

    if ($action eq "link"){
      # hack around potential race conditions -- will only be an issue during linking
      my $tries = 4;
      until ($retCode == 0 or $tries == 0){
        last if ($retCode = system($cmd)) == 2; #compile error; stop trying
        $tries--;
      };
    }
    else{
      $retCode = system($cmd);
    }

    return $retCode if $action eq "depend"; #stop here for dependlist building

    lock(@retCodes);  #lock to keep thread-safe
    push(@retCodes, ($retCode>>8));    

    #testing
    if($retCode != 0){
      if($verbose){
        print "\n\t\t*** ERROR IN $comp: $@ !! ***\n";
        print "\t\t*** Action: $cmd -->> Error Level: " . ($retCode >>8) . "\n";
      }
      lock(@failedComponents);  #lock to keep thread-safe
      push(@failedComponents, $comp);
    }

    return $retCode;
}


# searches the $strDataFile for the given $strComponentName, then 
# fills the @dir_array with the appropriate directories for that component
sub GetDirs {
   # ... <SNIP> ...
   # mostly irrelevant

   return @dir_array;
}


#-----------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------  Documentation / Usage / Help ------------------
=head1 NAME

  sample - Using GetOpt::Long and Pod::Usage

=head1 SYNOPSIS

  buildmom.pl [options]
   options:
     -help            Brief help message
     -man             Full documentation
     -comp s          The list of components to perform actions on (from your comps.dat) | space delimited
     -COMPLIST        Legacy support for old build script
     -action          A list of actions to perform on each component; executed in the order given  | space delimited
                      Available actions include clean, depend, build, link
     -clthreads       Number of threads used during compiling
     -linkthreads     Number of threads used during linking
     -verbose         Enables addition build output - may increase build time


=head1 DESCRIPTION

B<buildmom.pl> is used to perform various actions on your Momentum C++ project.

 Parameters worth note:
  -comps | [optional: defaulted to ALL] The list of components from your comps.dat file on which to have the
           specified actions performed. Example usage:  buildmom.pl -comps FOUNDATION COMMON TRANSPORT SERVER

  -COMPLIST | [optional: legacy support] This is the same as the `-comps` parameter, with the exception that it allows 
               legacy support for older parameter passing (e.g., -COMPLIST=FOUNDATION:COMMON:TRANSPORT:SERVER)

  -action | [optional: defaulted to `clean depend build link`] The set of actions, in order, which you want performed
             on the comps list. Available actions include: 

                clean: Executes `make clean` for each component specified(excluding ffsfld)
                depend: Builds the make depend list for each component specified
                build: Builds each component specified (formerly 'the first pass')
                link: Links each component specified (formerly 'the second pass')

  -clthreads | [optional: defaulted to 100%] Specifies the number of threads to use during compilation
  -linkthreads | [optional: defaulted to 75%] Specifies the number of threads to use during linking
      { For certain actions, specifically clean and depend, <buildmom.pl> will assume 100% thread usage every time.
        These actions are lightweight, and the performance loss from these actions is minimal. If you specify multiple actions
        e.g., buildmom.pl -actions clean depend build link, the script will consume 100% CPU for a couple of minutes while performing
        the `clean` and `depend` steps, and then throttle back to the specified number of threads. 

        Another example: buildmom.pl -actions clean depend build link -clthreads 2 -linkthreads 2
                    On a 4 core non-HT system, you would see your CPU usage jump to 100% for a few minutes while
                    we perform the `clean` and `depend` steps. Once compilation begins, your CPU usage will throttle 
                    back down to ~50% due to the number of threads specified. }
=cut
```

### Assumptions

Like I said, I'm pretty new to both Perl and multithreading. The primary assumption I've made here that I'm really not sure about is the number of threads to use. I've throttled it based on the number of cores available on the machine - is that the correct way to go about it? I assumed that anything >#cores would just cause some thrashing and competition of resources; is that accurate?

Comment: It appears you may be using GNU `make`.  What advantage are you're hoping to get beyond that obtained from using something like `make -j16`?

Comment: Nothing extraordinary - a couple of things that come to mind are `exe` directories can't be threaded, so there's little benefit to using `make -j#` over building multiple `exe`s together. Also, logging was an issue - but with make V4, that's no longer a problem. This kind of spiraled from a fix to a rewrite of what we already had.

Comment: "What advantage are you're hoping to get beyond that obtained from using something like make -j16?" -- also, where's the fun in that :)

Comment: @MrDuk: I deleted the comment because your description seems to contradict itself on this, and I'd need to read through the code to be sure which is accurate.

Comment: Why not experimenting with number of threads and taking notes? :)

Comment: @mpapec Hah, good idea :) Unfortunately though, a full run of the build can be upwards of 60-70 minutes long .. so that gets tedious heh